# Why DSLR Pro can access my Canon 500D on Windows 64bit system?

Tags: vb.net, edsdk

Hello dearest community,

Currently I am building a Canon EDSDK Application using VB.NET that access a Canon 500D camera. It's a DLSR system. I've read that the EDSDK is only working on 32 bit system, thus my application only capable of running on a 32 bit system.

But, I just installed DLSR pro (http://www.breezesys.com/DSLRRemotePro/support.htm), it can access my camera, regardless of the operating system : 32bit/64bit.

How do they able to do it?

Is there a new EDSKD that can access camera in 64 bit OS?
I am using a 2.6 EDSDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

64-bit Windows supports 32-bit applications.

Comment: Yes it is. But the driver that come with Canon DLSR is not able to run in 64 environment. I've tested it, and it fail. Somehow the application DSLRemotePro use different mechanism on accessing the Canon DLSR camera